# Create a login page for a shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Below I have a shiny app in which the contents of body and sidebars are related to tab selection, now I want to create a login page with the logic described [here](https://www.listendata.com/2019/06/how-to-add-login-page-in-shiny-r.html) or any other way.. but while I hide plots and sliders I cannot hide sidebars tabPanels and boxes as I want initially.

```
menu <- controlbarMenu(
  id = "controlbarMenu",
  controlbarItem(
    "Tab 1",
    "Welcome to tab 1"
  ),
  controlbarItem(
    "Tab 2",
    numericInput("num", "Observations:", 200, min = 1, max = 1000, step = 100)
  )
)

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
library(shinyauthr)

# dataframe that holds usernames, passwords and other user data
user_base <- tibble::tibble(
  user = c("user1", "user2"),
  password = sapply(c("pass1", "pass2"), sodium::password_store),
  permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
  name = c("User One", "User Two")
)

shinyApp(
  
  
  ui = tags$body(class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open",dashboardPage(
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading",titleWidth = 450),
    
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(minified = F, collapsed = F,
                               h4("Investment Selected"),
                               uiOutput("mytab11"), uiOutput("mytab12")
                               
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      # logout button
      div(class = "pull-right", shinyauthr::logoutUI(id = "logout")),
      
      # login section
      shinyauthr::loginUI(id = "login"),
      h3('Results'),
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("InsiderTraining",
                           box(
                             title = " Table", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                             collapsible = TRUE,width = 12,
                             dataTableOutput("Input"))),
                  
                  tabPanel("Tax Loss Harvesting",
                           box(
                             title = " Table", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                             collapsible = TRUE,width = 12,
                             dataTableOutput("Input2")))
      )
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(width = 300,
                                     h4("Insider Trading Parameters"),
                                     uiOutput("mytab21"), uiOutput("mytab22"), uiOutput("mytab32")
                                     
                                     
    ),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  )),
  server = function(input, output) {
    credentials <- shinyauthr::loginServer(
      id = "login",
      data = user_base,
      user_col = user,
      pwd_col = password,
      sodium_hashed = TRUE,
      log_out = reactive(logout_init())
    )
    
    # Logout to hide
    logout_init <- shinyauthr::logoutServer(
      id = "logout",
      active = reactive(credentials()$user_auth)
    )
    
    output$Input<-renderDataTable({
      # Show only when authenticated
      req(credentials()$user_auth)
      datatable(mtcars)
    })
    output$Input2<-renderDataTable({
      # Show only when authenticated
      req(credentials()$user_auth)
      datatable(mtcars2)
    })
    output$mytab11 <- renderUI({
      # Show only when authenticated
      req(credentials()$user_auth)
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="InsiderTraining"',
                         textInput("StockTicker", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "NFLX"),
                         
        ))
    })
    
    output$mytab21 <- renderUI({
      # Show only when authenticated
      req(credentials()$user_auth)
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="InsiderTraining"',
                         selectInput("InsiderTradingModel", "Insider Trading Model",
                                     c("Dynamic" = "Dynamic",
                                       "AI based" = "AIbased"))
                         
        ))
    })
    output$mytab22 <- renderUI({
      # Show only when authenticated
      req(credentials()$user_auth)
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="Switching"',
                         selectInput("InsiderTradingModel2", "Insider Trading Model 2",
                                     c("Dynamic" = "Dynamic",
                                       "BI based" = "BIbased"))
                         
        ))
    })
    output$mytab32 <- renderUI({
      # Show only when authenticated
      req(credentials()$user_auth)
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="Tax Loss Harvesting"',
                         menu
        ))
    })
    
  }
)
```

Comment: [shinymanager](https://datastorm-open.github.io/shinymanager/) could he useful for you.

Comment: great package indeed I used it https://datastorm-open.github.io/shinymanager/ and solved